# 3 divs side-by-side, full height with header (210x110x*)

Tags: css, html

I have been beating myself up for way too long to try to figure this out. Time to give up and ask if anybody already has code they can provide me to do what it is I am after.

[image]

I do not want or need a footer with this design.

All three columns need to be full height.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work if you floated only the first two columns and then set the width for the third one to `auto` (which is the default):

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#header {
  height:40px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#column-1 {
  width:210px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
}
#column-2 {
  width:110px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}
#column-3 {
  height:100%;
  background-color:gray;
}

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="column-1"></div>
<div id="column-2"></div>
<div id="column-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I went about it without the use of a script. May be a better choice to use javascript to achieve the desired height since `calc()` does not have the best support.

Here is the html:

```
<header></header>
<div class="leftCont"></div><!--
--><div class="centerCont"></div><!--
--><div class="rightCont"></div>
```

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: brown;
}

.leftCont, .centerCont, .rightCont {
    display: inline-block;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

.leftCont {
    width: 210px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
}

.centerCont {
    width: 110px;
    background: #4b4b4b;
}

.rightCont {
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
    background: tan;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo, remove "show" in url to view code.](http://jsfiddle.net/888wr/1/show/)

---

jQuery solution:

```
var wH = $(window).height() - 70, // Grabs the window's height and removes 70 pixels(header height)
    wW = $(window).width() - 335; // Same deal but for the width.

$('.leftCont, .centerCont, .rightCont').css({height: wH});
$('.rightCont').css({width: wW});
```

Fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/888wr/6/)

Comment: It is due to jsfiddle.net there is nothing that is bigger then the browsers window. You also included nothing that showed what you tried so you could work with what has been provided to you....

Comment: @JoshPowell if calc() does not have the best support for height will it always work for width? And also will calc() work in all browsers?

Comment: @Zword calc() has ie8 or ie9 support but the problem with calc() is due to the bad mobile phone support. I can provide a jQuery solution if you would like.

Comment: Josh & @Zword & Krister ... so I have been playing around with all three of the designs and all three appear to be working on my end. The big difference between the ones of Josh and Zword are the use of "inline-block" and "table-cell". I am at a point now where I am up for accepting either of these two answers (I would do both if I could). What are the thoughts on which I should mark as the answer? The others I will give a vote-up for.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing a solution which uses a single line jQuery for height measurements to fit display within screen without scrollbars around.Width is adjusted automatically.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">header (full width)</div>
<div id="columns">
    <div class="column red">210 px</div>
    <div class="column green">110 px</div>
    <div class="column grey">Remaining</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,#header{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#header{
    background-color:blue;
    height:30px;
}
#columns{
    width:100%;
}
.column{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
    min-width:250px;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
    min-width:110px;
}
.grey{
    background-color:grey;
    width:100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.column').height($(window).height()-$('#header').outerHeight());
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwCm2/2/) / Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/QwCm2/2/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">HEADER</div>
<div style="background-color:red;width:210px;float:left;">WERWER</div>
<div style="background-color:green;width:110px;float:left;">cvbcvbcvb</div>
<div style="background-color:gray;margin-left:320px;">ASDASD</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot about equal height. You need to add style to `<body>` and add some height to the divs, say, 3000px, so example becomes like this:

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="background-color:blue;">HEADER</div>
<div style="background-color:red;width:210px;float:left;height:3000px;">WERWER</div>
<div style="background-color:green;width:110px;float:left;height:3000px;">cvbcvbcvb</div>
<div style="background-color:gray;margin-left:320px;height:3000px;">ASDASD</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha.

html

```
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>
<div class="left1">
    left1
</div>
<div class="left2">
    left2
</div>
<div class="right">
    right
</div>
```

Css

```
.header {height:10%; width:100%; background-color:blue;}
.left1 {height:90%; width:210px; background-color:red; float:left;}
.left2 {height:90%; width:110px; background-color:green; float:left;}
.right {height:90%; width:100%; background-color:gray; float:left;}
```

jQuery

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".right").css("width", "-=320px");
});
```

This should put you on the right path. Hope it helps.
Oh, and then give them full height. That part should be easy for you.